# CSS: Image and text to the right on one line, no flow text?

Tags: css, alignment

I want to display an image with text to the right of that image. This should all be on one line and inside some more text. I dont want the rest of the text to flow around the image.

Example:

*Some Text  ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.*

**my image and my text**

*Some more text ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.*

I dont want the text after the image to flow around it. I tried float:left for the image, which aligns it to the left, but I dont know how to say that only some text goes next to it.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/2BJ7J/

Basically you're floating the image and text to the left with a container.

```
.container {
    width:480px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    overflow:auto;
}
.container img {
    float:left;
    width:260px;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
}
.container .text {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}



<div class="container">
    <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01452/fer1_1452403i.jpg" />
    <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sagittis, lorem eget pulvinar faucibus, diam tortor dapibus sapien, a egestas massa arcu ac risus. Ut tempor condimentum tincidunt. Donec vehicula, dui ornare ornare mollis, arcu nibh interdum ipsum, eu condimentum enim nunc id enim
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which width? The container? It will still work but the container will stretch to the width of it's parent. You can avoid this by setting the container to be display:inline-block

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
p { line-height:1.5; outline:1px dashed green }

.left-img span { /* span would be `img` in your project */
    float:left;
    margin-right:1em;
    /* BEG not needed for image */
    background-color:gray;
    width:20px;
    height:200px;
    outline:1px dotted;
     /* END not needed for image */
}

.left-img + p { clear:left; }
​
```

HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum ....</p>
<p class="left-img"><span></span>More text</p>
<!-- Replace <span></span> with <img>
---- working code would be:
---- <p class="left-img"><img src="...">More text</p>
-->
<p>Lorem ipsum ....</p>
​
```

Look at the semantics of your mark-up and take advantage of the natural document flow. The last line of the CSS above is the key: "The `<p>` following a `left-img` class needs to return to normal document flow."

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/MP8GJ/1/

Comment: Just pretend <span></span> is <img>: Answer updated. See 'working code would be...'

Comment: The first line of CSS would need to swap "span" for "img" as well. ie: `.left-img img {...}` instead of .left-img span {...}